# Reactjs - Inlinestyle "top" and "left"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to align different circles around the perimeter of a larger circle, and in order to do that I must adjust `top:` and `left:` for each div.

I'm trying to do this inline in the following way:

```
for(var i = 0; i < n_circles; i++){

  var posx = divHeigth/2 + Math.round(radius * (Math.cos(theta[i]))) + "px";
  var posy = divHeigth/2 - Math.round(radius * (Math.sin(theta[i]))) + "px";
  console.log("X: " + posx + " Y: " + posy)
  var scope = {
      position: "absolute",
      top: "300px",
      left: {posx},
      backgroundColor: "white"
 }
 var circle = <div className="circles" style={{scope}}></div>
 circles.push(circle)
}
```

However if I replace `{top}` with hard coded text like `"300px"` it works fine.
As you can see I log `posx` and `posy` and their values look fine(`300px`, `200px` etc..) But if I use the variables, it doesnt even get registered in Developers tool?

How can I style `top` and `left` inline in Reactjs?

Comment: I think the issue is that your `{posx}` becomes a JSON object as it is in the JS portion of your code rather than your JSX (HTML) portion. See my answer below, this should fix it, but I have not tested it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0; i < n_circles; i++){

  var posx = divHeigth/2 + Math.round(radius * (Math.cos(theta[i]))) + "px";
  var posy = divHeigth/2 - Math.round(radius * (Math.sin(theta[i]))) + "px";
  console.log("X: " + posx + " Y: " + posy)
  var scope = {
      position: "absolute",
      top: "300px",
      left: {posx}, <---- this is wrong, should simply be "left: posx,"
      backgroundColor: "white"
 }
 var circle = <div className="circles" style={{scope}}></div>
 circles.push(circle)
}
```

You do not need the curly brackets around your variable as you are applying it to JS portion of your your code (not HTML/JSX).